# Plot a matrix of colour hex codes

Tags: r, image, hex

I'm trying to plot a box which fade between three colours. It should be red on top left, blue on top right and white at the bottom.

Here's what I've tried:

```
##Change from red to blue as move left to right, fade to white as move from top to bottom

data<-matrix(1:(255*255),ncol=255,nrow=255)

rb<-colorRampPalette(c("red","blue"))(255)

colsMat<-matrix(nrow=255,ncol=255)

for(col in rb){
  idx<-which(rb==col)
  colsMat[idx,]<-colorRampPalette(c(col,"blue"))(255)
}

colsVec<-as.vector(colsMat)

image(data,col=colsVec,xaxt="n",yaxt="n")
```

I can get it to go from red to blue (but need to add the white) like this:

```
data<-matrix(1:255,ncol=255,nrow=255)
image(data,col=rb,xaxt="n",yaxt="n")
```

Comment: [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11773295/1478381) looks pretty close to what you are trying to do. Perhaps that will help?

Comment: That looks just different enough to put me off for now - if I can't find another solution I will try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rb<-colorRampPalette(c("red","blue"))(255)
trans<-sapply(seq(from=0,to=1,length.out=255),function(op) rgb(1,1,1,op))

image(matrix(1:255,ncol=255,nrow=255),col=rb,xaxt="n",yaxt="n")
par(new=T)
image(t(matrix(255:1,ncol=255,nrow=255)),col=trans,xaxt="n",yaxt="n")
```

Comment: +1 great answer and great to answer you own question!